Getting access to Spotify API and get the access token
I'm building a music player app, and I don't know why my request to access the Spotify API is declined and I can't fetch the correct info of artists.
My application is currently running on Microsoft Egde, my desired target is to fetch 18 artists, which displayed on a carousel slider, containing 6 Vietnamese artists on the first slide, 6 US artists on the second slide and the remaining 6 UK artists on the third slide. Here is my AllArtists.jsx file:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './AllArtists.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const AllArtists = () => {
    const [vnArtists, setVnArtists] = useState([]);
    const [usArtists, setUsArtists] = useState([]);
    const [ukArtists, setUkArtists] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getSpotifyAccessToken = async () => {
            const clientId = 'my_client_id_code';
            const clientSecret = 'my_client_secret_code';
            const authaccessToken = `${clientId}:${clientSecret}`;
            const accessToken = btoa(authaccessToken);
            

            try {
                const response = await axios.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
                    'grant_type=client_credentials',
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Authorization': `Basic ${accessToken}`,
                            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                        }
                    }
                );
                return response.data.access_token;
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error receiving Spotify API access token", error);
                return null;
            }
        };

        const fetchArtists = async () => {
            const token = await getSpotifyAccessToken();

            if (!token) {
                console.error('Failed to get access token');
                return;
            }

            try {
                const headers = {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                };

                const vnArtistsResponse = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', {
                    headers, 
                    params: {
                        q: 'artist:*',
                        type: 'artist',
                        market: 'VN',
                        limit: 6,
                    },
                });

                const usArtistsResponse = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', {
                    headers, 
                    params: {
                        q: 'artist:*',
                        type: 'artist',
                        market: 'US',
                        limit: 6,
                    },
                });

                const ukArtistsResponse = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/search', {
                    headers, 
                    params: {
                        q: 'artist:*',
                        type: 'artist',
                        market: 'GB',
                        limit: 6,
                    },
                });

                setVnArtists(vnArtistsResponse.data.artists.items);
                setUsArtists(usArtistsResponse.data.artists.items);
                setUkArtists(ukArtistsResponse.data.artists.items);

            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching artists from Spotify API', error);
            }
        };

        fetchArtists();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
        <div className='all-artists'>
            <div className='all-artists-line justify-content-between'>
                <h3 className='artists-home-part-title'>All Artists:</h3>
                <p className='text-end show-all'>Show All</p>
            </div>
            <div id='artistsCarousel1' className='carousel slide' data-bs-ride='carousel'>
                <div className='carousel-inner'>
                    {vnArtists.length > 0 && (
                        <div className='carousel-item active'>
                            <div className='row artists-row'>
                                {vnArtists.map(artist => (
                                    <div key={artist.id} className='col-2'> 
                                        <div className='artists-card'>
                                            <img src={artist.images[0]?.url} className='d-block rounded-circle artists-images' alt={artist.name} />
                                            <h5 className='artists-name'>{artist.name}</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                    {usArtists.length > 0 && (
                        <div className='carousel-item'>
                            <div className='row artists-row'>
                                {usArtists.map(artist => (
                                    <div key={artist.id} className='col-2'> 
                                        <div className='artists-card'>
                                            <img src={artist.images[0]?.url} className='d-block rounded-circle artists-images' alt={artist.name} />
                                            <h5 className='artists-name'>{artist.name}</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                    {ukArtists.length > 0 && (
                        <div className='carousel-item'>
                            <div className='row artists-row'>
                                {ukArtists.map(artist => (
                                    <div key={artist.id} className='col-2'> 
                                        <div className='artists-card'>
                                            <img src={artist.images[0]?.url} className='d-block rounded-circle artists-images' alt={artist.name} />
                                            <h5 className='artists-name'>{artist.name}</h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
                <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#artistsCarousel1" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#artistsCarousel1" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default AllArtists;



Looks like you're passing in the strings 'my_client_id_code' and 'my_client_secret_code' into the Authorization header. Unless these are just placeholders to avoid exposing your secret keys here, these are not valid keys. If you have created an app on the Spotify Developer portal (documentation here), you can find your Client Id and Client Secret by clicking on the app in your Spotify developer dashboard.
